# Type mismatch, expected: (HNil) => routing.Route, actual: StandardRoute

Tags: scala, routes

I am very new to Scala and tried writing an Spray API example using SBT  for practice but getting below issue.

[image: Issue with routing API ** Type Mismatch]

```
 import spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp 
 import akka.actor.ActorSystem 
 object ScalaBay extends App with SimpleRoutingApp { 
    implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem() 
    startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) { 
         get { path("hello") { 
            complete { "welcome" } 
               } 
         } 
    } 
 }
```

1. I have created a routing API using spray and Akka.
2. once server starts with localhost address, once it gets path="hello" it should complete with some success message.
3. But getting the error "Type mismatch, expected: (HNil) => routing.Route, actual: StandardRoute" while routing to after giving the path.

Please help me with how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a place where you need to use a lambda syntax as the input is a function, not a value, just like the error suggests. `HNil` in Spray routing means you've defined no params or entities to be extracted from the route, so the function defined is defined from `HNil`, the empty `HList` type, but it's of the form `HNil => routing.Route`, so you need to use `_ => route` somewhere.

```
 import spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp 
 import akka.actor.ActorSystem 
 object ScalaBay extends App with SimpleRoutingApp { 
    implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem() 
    startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) { 
         get { path("hello") { _ => 
            complete("welcome")
           } 
         } 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @flavian for help. please see the below error I am still getting after modifying code as per you suggestion.                                                           Type mismatch, expected: (HNil) => routing.Route, actual: (RequestContext) => Unit.     Could you please tell me how it would be resolved in IntelliJ IDE.  Thanks.